# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[data-scroll][href*=#]:not([href=#])

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, hyperlink, jquery-animate

I have a WordPress where on the homepage you have a pulsating triangle where you can click on it and it scrolls down to the introduction of the website.

I keep getting the following error;

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[data-scroll][href*=#]:not([href=#])
```

The only bit of jQuery i can see from the scroll is the following;

```
    /* Scroll to intro */
    jQuery('.wad-icon-triangle').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var targetId = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        var targetOff = jQuery(targetId).offset();

        var targetPosition = (targetOff.top - 60);
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: targetPosition
        }, 2000);
    });
```

The is the site - Click [HERE](http://www.wearedigitl.co.uk)

Even commenting out that snippet of jQuery doesn't seem to do anything.

I've also found this bit of jQuery where the problem may be - i've added the "" but still doesnt make a difference.

```
// Only anchor with data-scroll and not only hash
        jQuery('a[data-scroll][href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = jQuery(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    jQuery('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 600, 'easeInOutExpo');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

It's in the script.js file if you view the source.

Comment: jQuery('a[data-scroll][href*="#"]:not([href="#"])') seems to work fine. Could you put the second code on your website? I would like to see how the new selector is interpreted by jQuery.

Comment: It may depend on your jQuery version, since the selector seems to be tricky... Can you check it out ?